# Validate input type of date in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, date

Here is an issue.

**Please note that this issue does NOT appear when the field is `required`**

I have an input that has type date, such as:

```
<label for="due-date">Due date</label>
<input
  type="date"
  name="dueDate"
  id="dueDate"
  ng-model="form.dueDate"
>
<div ng-if="myForm.dueDate.$touched && !myForm.dueDate.$valid" ng-messages="myForm.dueDate.$error">
  <p class="form-error-text" ng-show="myForm.dueDate.$error">
    Please set correct date (yyyy-mm-dd)
  </p>
</div>
```

Visual demostration:
[image]

According to this `ng-if="myForm.dueDate.$touched && !myForm.dueDate.$valid"` the field is checked for validation and if it is not valid then `Please set correct date (yyyy-mm-dd)` will be shown. As you might noticed the field is NOT required field. Which means that by default `myForm.dueDate.$valid` is `true`.

Scenarios:

1. Field is NOT touched and date is valid (since its not required and default is true)

   [image]
   expected: works as expected
2. Field is touched and date is valid

   [image]
   expected: works as expected
3. Field is touched and date is NOT valid
   [image]
   expected: error message must be shown, since the field is not valid
4. Field is touched and date is firstly set as `/01/01/2015` and then altered to `/01/mm/2015` (which is NOT valid)

   [image]
   expected: works as expected
5. Field is touched and date is firstly set as `/01/01/2015` and then altered to `/dd/mm/yyyy` (which is valid according to the `ng-if="myForm.dueDate.$touched && !myForm.dueDate.$valid` statement)

   [image]
   expected: NO error message must be shown, since the field is valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is a bug with AngularJS v1.4.x and the clear explanation is [in this github PR](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/12902). There is already a solution offered by @gkalpak, but the PR is under [milestone](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/milestones/1.4.x) that might take a while to fix.